# Filename with # in the name fails to download

Tags: javascript, php, centos7

**Background**

I have a PHP application running on a CentOS server. The front end is using an ajax call to hit a PHP script. The script returns a file from the server and downloads it to the client.

**Problem**

If the file has a `#` in the name, the file fails to download.

**Example**

`File#Name.pdf` = Does not download correctly

`FileName.pdf` = Does download correctly

This is the PHP used to retrieve the files,

```
if( isset($_GET['path'])) {
    $path = $_GET['path'];
    if(!file_exists($path)) {
        die('file not found');
    } else {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$path);
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($path));
        readfile($path);
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        exit;
    }
}
```

**Question**

Why is the file failing to download when the `#` is in the name?

Comment: Does it work if you use `File%23Name.pdf` in the URL?

Comment: What is happening in the failure case? Does your ajax call get a response? Can you use your browser profiler to see what the headers or body of the response object is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, is the filename coming in from a GET request? If so the # is probably getting rewritten as a %23. Try

```
$path = urldecode($_GET['path']);
```

Comment: No prob. In general, in php be suspicious of any text value that came to you from the client. By suspicious I mean both from a security/malicious user standpoint, and also from a "is this really what I think it is" standpoint.